# How to disable animation for md-sidenav in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, animation, material-design

I am using md-sidenav from Material Design in angularjs.

**Question** : Is it possible to disable animation of md-sidenav when it opens and closes? It seems its opening and closing are animated by default.

```
<md-sidenav md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left">
Left Nav!
</md-sidenav>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try add the attribute md-no-ink to the sidevav

```
<md-sidenav md-no-ink md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left">
Left Nav!
</md-sidenav>
```

Or remove all animations overriding the CSS:

```
.md-ripple-container, .md-ripple-placed {
    transition: none;
}
```

reference: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ngmaterial/HJ01ZHEbOQA/discussion

Comment: Do I need to add this attribute with surrounding asterisks as you have shown in the answer?

Comment: Sorry, i tried to add bold style to the code sample. it was a formatting error of the editor. No need for asterisks :)

Comment: I tried both the css and the attribute but the menu is still animated. I am trying to detect certain browsers and disable animations for the ones that can't handle it... Like IE and Safari

Comment: Update: I updated to Angular 1.4.4 and latest Master of Angular-Material and now disabling effects work.

Answer (score 3):

I generate a `disable-animations.css` with next:

```
* {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

I include this file at the end of all.

If you need disable specific controls, use:

```
disable-animation,
disable-animation *,
.disable-animation,
.disable-animation * {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This CSS worked for me. I looked through the AngularMaterial CSS file and removed all references to animations. KA-BOOM!

```
/**
* fix md-sidenav lag by removing animation
**/

.md-sidenav-backdrop {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}

md-sidenav.md-closed-add,
md-sidenav.md-closed-remove,
md-sidenav.md-closed-add.md-closed-add-active, 
md-sidenav.md-closed-remove.md-closed-remove-active,
md-sidenav.md-locked-open-remove-active,
md-sidenav.md-closed.md-locked-open-add-active

{
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```